# Enable TLS 1.3 on IIS 10 windows server 2019

Tags: ssl, iis, encryption, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I am unable to enable TLS 1.3 on IIS 10 apps on windows server 2019. I have enable the schannel server TLS DWORD registry. But IIS is still choosing TLS 1.2 as the max supported cipher suite during handshake. I have deployed apps on TLS 1.3 on caddy on the same server with the same certificate.

Windows server 2019 supports TLS 1.3. I tried finding resources for support with IIS 10; they seems to be very old and officially there is no news for this? As anyone managed to do it with any IIS plugin or something?

Answer (score 8):

Windows server 2019 does not support TLS 1.3, Windows server 2022 supported.

More information you can refer to this link: [TLS protocol version support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-#tls-protocol-version-support).